# What's the correct syntax to declare an object of type in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm learning Typescript and I'm trying to write the proper syntax to define an interface for the state variable classRecord but I can't seem to get it right.

```
interface ClassInterfaceObject {
  id: string
  className: string
  studentsInClass: string[]
}

export interface ClassRecords {
  ClassInterfaceObject: []
}

const [classRecord, setClassRecord] = useState<ClassRecords>([
  {
    id: '1000',
    className: 'CS101',
    studentsInClass: ['Tom', 'Bernard', 'Joseph'],
  },
  {
    id: '1001',
    className: 'CS102',
    studentsInClass: ['Bruce', 'Mary', 'Jack'],
  },
  {
    id: '1002',
    className: 'CS103',
    studentsInClass: ['Janet', 'Mercy', 'Sally'],
  },
])
```

My end goal is to have the data in the following format:

```
0: {id: '1000', className: 'CS101', studentsInClass: Array(3)...}
1: {id: '1001', className: 'CS102', studentsInClass: Array(3)...}
2: {id: '1002', className: 'CS103', studentsInClass: Array(3)...}
```

Comment: `Array<ClassInterfaceObject>` or `ClassInterfaceObject[]`

Comment: Some clarification please

Comment: Nope that didn't work